# Can I use a wine cooler as a PC case?

Tags: motherboard, cooling, case

I've always wanted a custom PC case that housed my routers, external NAS, motherboard and hard drives that kept everything at a steady temperature since my room does not get the best cooling (very hot during summer).

I'm wondering if I house everything in a wine cooler such as the following and set the temperature to 18 degrees if that would be a good or bad idea.

I don't know what the typically running temperatures for motherboards are, but I think this might be an awesome way to keep everything cool without the need for additional noisy fans.

[image]

http://www.salton.com/products/view/wine-cellars/WC-2053

Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Link does not work unless you log in

Comment: A wine cooler is not designed to chill something that generates heat. Instead of listening to computer fans you'll have to listen to the wine coolers compressor instead.

Comment: @Nifle, you can Google the part number to [find info on it](http://www.411buyitnow.com/Countertop-Wine-Cellar-p/wc-2053.htm).

Comment: Nifle is probably right & how are you going to feed all the cables in/out? Tank cutter? PS: Link works if you go through the site's main menu to 'WIne Cellars' and then pick the WC-2053

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at liquid cooled computer cases as they are made for it...

Here are a couple links:

- [FrozenCPU](http://www.frozencpu.com/)
- [Liquid / Water Cooled Computer Cases](http://www.xoxide.com/watcoolcas.html)

Those links came from a Google search. Here are Wikipedia entries on the topic:

- [Water cooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_cooling)
- [Computer cooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cooling)

Comment: A water-cooling system is usually significantly more expensive than a small cooler.

Comment: True but looking for alternate solutions than a fans this is an option. While you might can make a wine cooler work it is probably not the best solution.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question in *any* way. Can you maybe explain why a wine cooler would *not* work? Any specific reason for not doing it?

Comment: I am unsure of the technicalities yet basically (in my understanding) fans or liquid cooling take the heat and pulls it away and spreads the heat from the source. Thus keeping the computer cool.

Answer (score 1):

Wine aficionado often like to keep their wares between 50-80% humidity. Computers prefer a lower humidity between 30-60%.

If the wine cooler supports manually setting the humidity, then sure, it sounds good. If however it is automatic, then it will probably keep the system too humid and puts it at risk for things like electrical problems and rusting. From what I can tell, this model is completely automatic for both humidity *and* temperature, meaning that it will be optimally set for **wine**, not a computer.